# Replace function in JavaScript By variable

Tags: javascript, random, str-replace

I need to replace `$` by Random how can I do this.
I want to convert this text from `Some texte here some text here` to be like this `Som(gb5t2)e t(gb95f)ext(ze6f5)e h(bs3e2)ere (avFe3)so(gEC3e)me (aFE98)tex(8FZq2)t h(dq9aA)ere(cZ3cC)`.

```
function String() {
    var str =  "Some texte here some text here".replace(/(.{3})/g, "$1$");
    var mystring = str;
    var find = "$";
    var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
    var fun = randomString();
    alert(mystring.replace(regex, fun));
    document.write(str);

    function randomString() {
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var string_length = 5;
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
        }
        document.randform.randomfield.value = " ( " + randomstring + " ) ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `replace` takes a function as an argument. You're passing in the result of the function, not the function itself.

Comment: Looks a lot like the obfuscated code I've had to clean up on hacked websites.  Are you a good guy or a bad guy?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean because i'm not a programmer i had collected this code from stackoverflow and other site like w3schools but i can't write this code right can you fix this code please

Comment: If you are not a programmer, may I ask what are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @cale_b  No this's a clean code i'm not hacker or a bad gay

Comment: really can i hack some think by this code hhhh are you serious man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some modifications to your code it should work now.

```
function String() {
var str =  "Some texte here some text here".replace(/(.{3})/g, function (x) 
{
return x + randomString();
});

document.write(str);

function randomString() {
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var string_length = 5;
var randomstring = '';
for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
}
return " ( " + randomstring + " ) ";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your function randomString() doesn't return anything, so fun is always going to be nothing. Secondly, your find regex doesn't work.

Try something with these two:

```
var find = '\\$+';

function randomString() {
   var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   var string_length = 5;
   var randomstring = '';

   for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
       var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
       randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
   }

   return randomstring;
}
```